# how to write functions in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Novice question: how would you write this in racket?

```
10x - 6 = 3x + 7
```

I am having a hard time trying to figure out where would I put the `= 3x + 7`.

Comment: The thing you have described does not look like a function.  That is, there's no clear input-output relationship described by `10x - 6 = 3x + 7`.  Other answers are trying to infer one, but I'd rather we don't guess.  Can you rephrase the above so that there is an input-output relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(= (- (* 10 x) 6)
   (+ (*  3 x) 7))
```

Of course, assuming that a value has been assigned previously to the `x` variable. Now, if the expression is to be evaluated as part of a function (as suggested by the title), then do this:

```
(define (test x)
  (= (- (* 10 x) 6)
     (+ (*  3 x) 7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathmatical conventions of precedence group that statement like so:

```
((10 * x) - 6) = ((3 * x) + 7)
```

In math we write operators in the middle of an expression: `foo OP bar`, but in Racket, the operator comes first: `(OP foo bar)`. So if you just shuffle each expression around to match the Racket way, you get:

```
((10 * x) - 6) = ((3 * x) + 7)   ;=> swap = and (10x - 6)
(= ((10 * x) - 6) ((3 * x) + 7)) ;=> swap - and 10x
(= (- (10 * x) 6) ((3 * x) + 7)) ;=> swap * and 10
(= (- (* 10 x) 6) ((3 * x) + 7)) ;=> swap + and 3x
(= (- (* 10 x) 6) (+ (3 * x) 7)) ;=> swap * and 3

(= (- (* 10 x) 6) (+ (* 3 x) 7)) ;=> done
```

Now that we've rearranged the expressions so the operators come first, we have a valid Racket expression.